# What is wrong with this code as I am not getting the desired output?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A generalized object declaration - Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myBooks(name,author,bookType,printCost,purchaseCost){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.bookType  =bookType;
    this.printCost = printCost;
    this.purchaseCost  =purchaseCost;
    var checkProfit = (function(){
        return this.printCost-this.purchaseCost;

    }());
}

var book1 = new myBooks('Elon Musk','Ashlee Vance','Biography',699,500);
document.write('Profit from '+ book1.name + ' = ' + book1.checkProfit);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I have written a basic code in Javascript in which I am declaring an object using constructor function. Here, in 20th line of my code, book1.checkProfit is getting value NaN while other variables are working fine. Can anyone explain the error in my code.

Comment: Why you are not use : `var checkProfit = this.printCost - this.purchaseCost` ?

Comment: I am trying to learn and apply the concept of immediately invoked anonymous function. Therefor, preferring this way.

Comment: `checkProfit` is a local variable in `myBooks`, you can't access it from outside of the function. Define it as a property, i.e. `this.checkProfit = ...`.

Comment: Okay. But even if I am using this.checkProfit, it is still returning NaN.

Comment: the last parentheses is on wrong place it should be `(function() {}) ()` instead of `(function{}())`

Comment: I dont think so as I have previously used it the same way and have achieved output.

Comment: @webdeb It'll work in either way.

Comment: @Teemu true, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that = this , this inside your checkProfit is window

```
function myBooks(name,author,bookType,printCost,purchaseCost){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.bookType  =bookType;
    this.printCost = printCost;
    this.purchaseCost  =purchaseCost;
    var that = this;
    this.checkProfit = (function(){
        return that .printCost-that.purchaseCost;

    }());
}
```

> > OR you can use bind

```
function myBooks(name,author,bookType,printCost,purchaseCost){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.bookType  =bookType;
    this.printCost = printCost;
    this.purchaseCost  =purchaseCost;
    var that = this;
    this.checkProfit = (function(){
        return that .printCost-that.purchaseCost;

    }.bind(this)());
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Its not working for me.

Comment: use this.checkProfit ,  you are tying to access the local variable of the function instance from outside

Comment: Rectified. Still not working.

Comment: @AkshitaBhatt You're doing something wrong. Piyush.kapoor's answer [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/39q6hufq/) (replaced `.write` with `.body.innerHTML`, since jsFiddle doesn't accept `.write`).

Comment: Thanks for the correct code, but still I am not able to understand the error in my code. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Well this one worked out for me. Have a look!

```
function myBooks(name,author,bookType,printCost,purchaseCost){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.bookType  =bookType;
    this.printCost = printCost;
    this.purchaseCost  =purchaseCost;
    var that =this;
    this.checkProfit = (function(){
        return parseInt(that.printCost)-parseInt(that.purchaseCost);
    }.bind(this)());
}
```